# How do I make the space around my Dash Plotly Graph Object the same Dark Theme?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm developing my first Dash Plotly metrics dashboard.  That stated, I was able to get most of the dashboard dark themed except the area around my plotly graph object. See below:
[image]

How can I get the area around my graph the same dark theme as the rest of the dashboard?

Below is the code I used to materialize the dashboard.

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, dcc, dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_design_kit as ddk
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account

df = query_job.to_dataframe()
df['dmand_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dmand_yr_mo']).dt.month
df.loc[:, 'price'] = df.loc[:, 'sales_dollars']/df.loc[:, 'ord_qty']
df.loc[:, 'predicted_sales'] = np.round(df.loc[:, 'predictions']*df.loc[:, 'price'])
df.loc[:, 'diff'] = np.round(np.abs(np.round(df.loc[:, 'predicted_sales'] - df.loc[:, 'sales_dollars'],2)))
#BUSINESS LINE
bl = df.groupby(['location_type', 'GLBL_BUS_LN_DESC']).agg({'ord_qty':'sum',
                                        'predictions':'sum',
                                        'sales_dollars':'sum',
                                        'predicted_sales':'sum', 
                                        'diff':'sum'}).reset_index()
bl.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
bl['sales_dollars'] = np.round(bl['sales_dollars'])
bl.dropna(inplace = True)
bl.loc[:, 'MAPE'] = np.round(np.round(bl.loc[:, 'diff']/ bl.loc[:, 'sales_dollars'], 4) * 100,2)
bl.loc[:, 'BIAS'] = np.round(np.round((bl.loc[:,'predicted_sales']- bl.loc[:, 'sales_dollars'])/ bl.loc[:, 'sales_dollars'], 4) * 100,2)


fig1 = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar( name='MAPE', x=bl['GLBL_BUS_LN_DESC'], y=bl['MAPE']),
    go.Bar(name='BIAS', x=bl['GLBL_BUS_LN_DESC'], y=bl['BIAS'])
])
fig1.update_layout(barmode='group', plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)')

colors = {
    'background': '#000000',
    'text': '#111111'
}
# initialize app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY])

# set app layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1('Demand Forecasting Model Overview',style={
            'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application to help assess predictors for furture demand forecasting models.
    ''', style={
            'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Dropdown(options = [{'label':'home_delivery', 'value':'home_delivery'},
                 {'label': 'shop_sales', 'value':'shop+sales'}],
                  id='location-dropdown'),
    dcc.Graph(id='Business Line MAPE', figure=fig1),
    html.H2(children='Demand Forecast by Business Line', style={
            'textAlign': 'center'}),
    dash_table.DataTable(
    data=bl.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in bl.columns],

    style_header={
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(30, 30, 30)',
        'color': 'white'
    },
    style_data={
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
        'color': 'white'
    },
)
    # dcc.Graph(id='Business Line BIAS', figure=fig2),
    # dcc.Graph(id='Month', figure=fig_month)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `paper_bgcolor` in your `update_layout` as below:

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', plot_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)',paper_bgcolor='rgb(0,0,0)')
```

[image]